# How to solve this?non-const reference must bind to lvalue

Tags: c++

the reference of a base class pointer can not bind to the derived class poiner?

```
class base
{

};
class derived : public base
{

};
int main()
{
    derived va;
    derived *p = &va;
    base * &rp = (base*)p;    //wrong, non-const reference must bind to lvalue
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Non-const lvalue reference can only bind to lvalues, but `(base *)p` is an rvalue

Comment: same error as writing `int &x = 1;`

Comment: why (base *)p is rvalue? Does cast change the object to temporary object?

Comment: yes, it makes a temporary of type `base *` initialized from `p`

Comment: Be careful what you mean by 'object'. There is one `derived` instance (on the stack) and *two* (or more) pointers to it. The pointers are being cast to different pointer types, and there is no copy or cast of the underlying `derived` instance

Answer (score 3):

> the reference of a base class pointer can not bind to the derived class poiner?

It can't. What you are doing however, is trying to bind **base** class pointer reference to a temporary **base** class pointer (rvalue). But since it's a non-const reference, it cannot bind to an rvalue.

You have two options, depending on your intention. Use a const reference, which can be bound to rvalues. This extends the lifetime of the temporary:

```
base * const &rp = (base*)p;
```

Or bind the reference to an lvalue:

```
base * b = p;
base * &rp = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do

```
base& rp = *p;
```

Alternatively, if you really want a reference to a pointer, you can do it like that:

```
base* tmp = p;
base*& rp = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to do

```
 base* rp = (base*)p;
```